# Separate sections of document

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have to parse document, which has nested structure.

It contains sections which has header and pairs of keys and values.

```
txt_1 = '''
header1:
  key1: 1a
  key2: 2b
'''

txt_2 = '''
section1:
  key1: 1a

section2:
  key2: 2b
  key3: 3c
'''
```

I wrote simple grammar in `pyparsing`, which works fine with simple document, which has only one section, but when I tried parse document with multiple sections separate by empty line the grammar fails.

```
HEADER = (
    (
        Word(alphanums)
        + Suppress(Literal(':'))
    ).setResultsName('header')
)
PARAM = Word(alphanums).setResultsName('param')
VALUE = Word(alphanums).setResultsName('value')

LINE = (
    Group(
        PARAM
        + Suppress(Literal(':'))
        + VALUE
    )
)

LINES = (
    OneOrMore(
        LINE
    )
).setResultsName('body')

SECTION = (
    Group(
        HEADER
        + LINES
    )
    .setResultsName('section')
)

GRAMMAR = OneOrMore(SECTION).setResultsName('section')

GRAMMAR.parseString(txt).asList()
```

for `txt_1` it works fine, but for `txt_2`, which has two sections separate with empty line part of section 2 is treated as part section 1.

```
[['section1', ['key1', '1a'], ['section2', 'key2']]]
```

I tried different approach with following tokens, but without any success.

```
N = White('\n', exact=1)
EMPTY = LineStart()+LineEnd()
```

Answer (score 1):

The observation that a new section begins with the pattern "***alphanum: alphanum:***" is leveraged in the below code. Negative lookahead `~` (*NotAny*) is used to stop the `body` parser from gobbling up the next section header.

The *setResultsName* parameter *listAllMatches* is set for the `line` result name (`*` suffix) so that the dictionary can list multiple matches.

*pyparsing* skips whitespace by default, except in certain situations, like when using *Combine*, so there is no need to consider it here.

```python
from pyparsing import *

COLON = Suppress(':')
param = Word(alphanums)("param")
value = Word(alphanums)("value")

line = Group(param + COLON + value)
new_section_check = (Word(alphanums) + COLON) * 2
body = OneOrMore(~new_section_check + line("line*"))

section = Group(Word(alphanums)("section") + COLON + body)
contents = OneOrMore(section)

text = """
section1:
  key1: 1a

section2:
  key2: 2b
  key3: 3c
"""

print(contents.parseString(text).dump())
```

which produces the following:

```python
[['section1', ['key1', '1a']], ['section2', ['key2', '2b'], ['key3', '3c']]]
[0]:
  ['section1', ['key1', '1a']]
  - line: [['key1', '1a']]
    [0]:
      ['key1', '1a']
      - param: 'key1'
      - value: '1a'
  - section: 'section1'
[1]:
  ['section2', ['key2', '2b'], ['key3', '3c']]
  - line: [['key2', '2b'], ['key3', '3c']]
    [0]:
      ['key2', '2b']
      - param: 'key2'
      - value: '2b'
    [1]:
      ['key3', '3c']
      - param: 'key3'
      - value: '3c'
  - section: 'section2'
```

Comment: Good use of negative lookahead to detect when a new section begins.